# Dynamic Fields Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am trying to make my form dynamic,where you can add fields yourself.
I tried the code below,but the click,doesn't trigger anything,nothing happens when i click on the add button,any help ?

HTML

```
    <form id="bookForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Book</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book[0].title" placeholder="Title" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book[0].isbn" placeholder="ISBN" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book[0].price" placeholder="Price" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- The template for adding new field -->
    <div class="form-group hide" id="bookTemplate">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="isbn" placeholder="ISBN" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" placeholder="Price" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

And this is my javascript that i included in the bottom of the body

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var titleValidators = {
    row: '.col-xs-4',   // The title is placed inside a <div class="col-xs-4"> element
    validators: {
    notEmpty: {
    message: 'The title is required'
    }
    }
    },
    isbnValidators = {
    row: '.col-xs-4',
    validators: {
    notEmpty: {
    message: 'The ISBN is required'
    },
    isbn: {
    message: 'The ISBN is not valid'
    }
    }
    },
    priceValidators = {
    row: '.col-xs-2',
    validators: {
    notEmpty: {
    message: 'The price is required'
    },
    numeric: {
    message: 'The price must be a numeric number'
    }
    }
    },
    bookIndex = 0;

    $('#bookForm')
    .formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    icon: {
    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
    'book[0].title': titleValidators,
    'book[0].isbn': isbnValidators,
    'book[0].price': priceValidators
    }
    })

    // Add button click handler
    .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
    bookIndex++;
    var $template = $('#bookTemplate'),
    $clone    = $template
    .clone()
    .removeClass('hide')
    .removeAttr('id')
    .attr('data-book-index', bookIndex)
    .insertBefore($template);

    // Update the name attributes
    $clone
    .find('[name="title"]').attr('name', 'book[' + bookIndex + '].title').end()
    .find('[name="isbn"]').attr('name', 'book[' + bookIndex + '].isbn').end()
    .find('[name="price"]').attr('name', 'book[' + bookIndex + '].price').end();

    // Add new fields
    // Note that we also pass the validator rules for new field as the third parameter
    $('#bookForm')
    .formValidation('addField', 'book[' + bookIndex + '].title', titleValidators)
    .formValidation('addField', 'book[' + bookIndex + '].isbn', isbnValidators)
    .formValidation('addField', 'book[' + bookIndex + '].price', priceValidators);
    })

    // Remove button click handler
    .on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
    var $row  = $(this).parents('.form-group'),
    index = $row.attr('data-book-index');

    // Remove fields
    $('#bookForm')
    .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="book[' + index + '].title"]'))
    .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="book[' + index + '].isbn"]'))
    .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="book[' + index + '].price"]'));

    // Remove element containing the fields
    $row.remove();
    });
    });
```

I included these libraries for jQuery

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form threw an error: **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).formValidation is not a function**

Did you remember to add the following scripts in addition to your jQuery library?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As a matter of fact,yes i had all of them except for the bootstrap.min.js,and now tht i added it,i didnt mention that i have the form inside a modal,so now when i click on the button of the modal it just opens then closes up,in the blink of an eye,by itself....could that be a jquery or some other library conflicts ? because i have many of them since i use blad.

Comment: I really don't know because I tried to duplicate your posted code on codepen and it was working like it should for me.  Perhaps you can take a look at it and see where the difference was in your own code:  [http://codepen.io/GunWanderer/pen/QEmmJo](http://codepen.io/GunWanderer/pen/QEmmJo)